# Pointer array and structure in C

Tags: c

I am nowhere lose to even guessing how come we get the given output . Can I please get some explanation? Also, any short and quick resources to try similar questions?

```
void main()
{
    struct a
    {
        char ch[10];
        char *str;
    };

    struct a s1={"Hyderabad","Bangalore"};
    printf("\n%c%c",s1.ch[0],*s1.str);
    printf("\n%s%s",s1.ch,s1.str);
    getch();
}
```

Ans: HB, HyderabadBangalore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct a s1={"Hyderabad","Bangalore"};` assigns "Hyderabad" to `ch` and "Bangalore" to `str`.

`printf("\n%c%c",s1.ch[0],*s1.str);` prints the first character of the strings. Since `ch` is an array, `ch[0]` represents its first character. Since `str` is a character pointer, it points to the first character of a string here. So, `*s1.str` will have value 'B'

`printf("\n%s%s",s1.ch,s1.str);` simply prints all characters of both strings.
Fundamentally, `ch` is equal to `&ch[0]`, the address of the first character in the array. And, str is pointer variable which holds the address of first character of the string literal "Bangalore".

Answer (score 0):

`%c` is only for single character. Example H. 
`$s` is for string. Example Hyderabad.

`s1.ch[0]` points to first character of String ch ->H
`*s1.str` is a pointer. It points to the value stored at address of str. It will be ->B 
Hence you get `HB`

`\n` means a new line (as in java).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your output according to requested question

```
void main()
    {
        struct a
        {
            char ch[10];
            char *str;
        };

        struct a s1={"Hyderabad","Bangalore"};
        printf("%c%c",s1.ch[0],*s1.Str[0]);
        printf("\t%s%s",s1.ch,s1.str);
        getch();
    }
```